# A minimal Erlang script for load testing

Tags: erlang, load-testing

I just started learning Erlang. My task to write a simple script for testing web applications. I hasn't found work script in the Internet, and Tsung too bulky for such a task. Is anyone can help me (give working example of script or link where I can found it)?

What would be possible to specify a URL, and concurrency, and time of testing and get the results. Thanks.

This links not help:

- http://effectiveqa.blogspot.com/2009/12/minimal-erlang-script-for-load-testing.html
  (not working, function example/0 undefined )
- http://www.metabrew.com/article/a-million-user-comet-application-with-mochiweb-part-1
  (work for socket, but I need concurrent testing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use for such purposes basho [bench](http://wiki.basho.com/Benchmarking.html). It not so hard to start with it and add your own cases. Also it contains script, which draw all results.

Answer (score 1):

Would like to build one? I would not recommend that way (because I have tried and there are so many things to consider to build one, especially spawning many processes and collecting the result back)

As you already know, I would recommend tsung, although it is bulky, it is a full load test application. I have gave up mine, and went back to tsung because could not properly handle opening/closing sockets with too many processes.

If you really want a simple one, I would use httperf. AFAKI, it works fine with single machine with multiple processes.

http://agiletesting.blogspot.ca/2005/04/http-performance-testing-with-httperf.html

Comment: if you want to see my code, it's here at https://github.com/bighostkim/loadtesterl

Comment: Thanks, I better look at your example.